# Calculating Bayesian posterior with uniform prior

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am looking to calculate the posterior probability of a pdf with

$$f(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}I_{0,\theta}(x)$$

and prior $$\pi(\theta) = \frac{3}{5}(\frac{5}{\theta})^4 I_{(5,\infty)}(\theta)$$

The result is supposedly $$\pi(\theta|x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{8}{14} (\frac{14}{\theta})^9 & \theta>14\\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases} $$

With prior data as 2,3,9,10,14. Could anyone explain how to get there?

Comment: Can you see why $\pi(\theta\mid \{2,3,9,10,14\})\propto\theta^{-9}1_{\theta>14}$?  So you only have to calculate the constant of proportionality.

Comment: Only partially. The part I struggle with is why only for theta > 14?

Comment: because $14$ is the sample maximum. The product of indicators is equal to the indicator of the joint event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{x}=[2,3,9,10,14]$. The likelihood is
$$f(\mathbf{x}|\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^5}\prod_{k=1}^5\mathbb{I}_{[0,\theta)}(x_k)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\theta^5} & \textrm{if } \ \ \theta > 14 \\
0 & \textrm{if } \ \ \theta \leq 14
\end{cases}
$$
This is because if $\theta$ is $14$ or less, at least one indicator is zero so the term becomes zero.
$$f(\mathbf{x}|\theta)\pi(\theta)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{5^3\cdot 3}{\theta^9}\mathbb{I}_{(5,\infty)}(\theta) & \textrm{if } \ \ \theta > 14 \\
0 & \textrm{if } \ \ \theta \leq 14
\end{cases}
$$
The normalizing constant is
$$(5^3\cdot 3)\int_{14}^\infty y^{-9}dy=(5^3\cdot 3)\frac{1}{8}14^{-8}=C$$
So we get
$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{C}\frac{5^3\cdot 3}{\theta^9}\mathbb{I}_{(5,\infty)}(\theta)=(8\cdot 14^8)\frac{1}{\theta^9}=\frac{8}{14}\frac{14^9}{\theta^9} & \textrm{if } \ \ \theta > 14 \\
0 & \textrm{if } \ \ \theta \leq 14
\end{cases}$$
We can ignore the indicator because we have a stronger condition with the $\theta > 14.$

Comment: Remember to upvote if you like the answer!

Comment: Here you go. Now do one for me.